# Get max row of pandas dataframe without a tiebraker policy

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `pandas` dataframe similar to the following and I want to group it by *"group"* and for each group (*a, b, c & d*) get the max values based on the *"value1"* column.

**In case of a tie, I want to get all rows that tied at the top**.

So, for this example input:

```
    group value1  value2
0       a    1.1     7.1
1       a    2.0     8.0
2       a    3.0     9.0
3       b    4.0    10.0
4       b    4.0    11.0
5       b    6.0    12.0
6       c    7.0    43.0
7       c    8.0    12.0
8       d    9.0    34.0
9       d    1.0     5.0
10      d    2.0     6.0
11      d    9.0     2.0
12      d    4.0     3.0
```

I would like to get this:

```
    group value1  value2
2       a    3.0     9.0
5       b    6.0    12.0
7       c    8.0    12.0
8       d    9.0    34.0
11      d    9.0     2.0  # no tiebreaker policy
```

This is what I have so far but `head(1)` does not deliver. What has to go in there instead?

`temp_df.sort_values('temp', ascending=False).groupby('Node').head(1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `apply` with a `lambda` that compares the value against the max value, this will return a boolean mask that you can use to mask the original df:

```
In [125]:
df[df.groupby('group')['value1'].apply(lambda x: x== x.max())]

Out[125]:
   group  value1  value2
2      a     3.0     9.0
5      b     6.0    12.0
7      c     8.0    12.0
8      d     9.0    34.0
11     d     9.0     2.0
```

Here is the mask:

```
In [126]:
df.groupby('group')['value1'].apply(lambda x: x== x.max())

Out[126]:
0     False
1     False
2      True
3     False
4     False
5      True
6     False
7      True
8      True
9     False
10    False
11     True
12    False
Name: value1, dtype: bool
```

Comment: thanks a lot! That is exactly what I was looking for